# What does pipe mean as array separator?

Tags: php, arrays

Today I found a block of code where an array was declared like this:

```
$array = ['user'|'manager'|'admin'];
```

Into the code context, the array is used to keep references of some classes named 'User', 'Manager' and 'Admin' respectively.

At first impression I thought that was a new array's separator for PHP 7 or something similar. But testing I get confused:

```
$array = ['user'|'manager'|'admin'];
var_dump($array);

// result:
array:1 [
  0 => "}wo{oer"
]
```

In other test, I used only letters:

```
$array = ['a'|'b'|'c'];

array:1 [▼
  0 => "c"
]


$array = ['a'|'b'];

array:1 [▼
  0 => "c"
]
```

I asked to the author what his code means, but I never receive response.

Comment: it's a bitwise operator http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: Why in the world would you do this though, that is the real question?

Comment: Perhaps `user`, `manager`, and `admin` are constants with values like `1`, `2`, and `4` -- and the programmer inadvertently quoted them.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Now now... don't give the guy a reason for me to reopen *lol!*

Comment: Hmm, still doesn't explain why you'd need the result to be an array though...

Comment: Actually, the code is intended be applied as a rule, for example in pseudo-code:  `are you a user?(into User class) ? or manager (into Manager Class)?, or admin (into Admin class)?`

Comment: Can you be both a User and a Manager?

Comment: Yes, at least one of them. Can be all of them also.

Comment: OK well using bitwise OR makes sense in that context but the code is still very odd and likely incorrect.